# Intercity Travel in the Philippines

Tags: overland, philippines, cities, manila

I wish to travel from Manila to Boracay in the Philippines. What are the options I have if I wish to do it over land?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

None. Boracay is an island, with no land connection to the island where Manila is on.

But I assume now you knew that. So let's find the next possible way. Renting vehicles might be a challenge since you will not return them at the place where you got them. So you will have to take buses, trains and ferries.

If you want to shorten the water travel as much as possible, most likely you will travel:

1. [Manila - Batangas](http://www.ph-commute.com/2008/03/how-to-commute-to-batangas.html) by bus
2. [Batangas - Calapan](http://www.supercat.com.ph/sched.asp?route=25) by ferry
3. [Calapan- Roxas](http://jam.com.ph/jam_liner_bus_schedule.html) by bus
4. [Roxas - Caticlan](http://starliteferriesinc.com/tripdetails.php?id=3) by ferry
5. [Caticlan - Boracay](http://boracayblog.myboracayguide.com/how-to-get-from-caticlan-to-boracay-29.html), again by ferry.

For most of the sections you will be able to find alternative providers, with different schedules. Google will be very helpful to make sure you get the best fitting schedule.

If you schedule it correctly, and if there are no other issues, the whole thing will take you the whole day (about from 5am to 10pm)

Please be aware of the following:

- Some of the ferries are not very reliable in schedule or might be even cancelled
- There is quite a high risk of pickpockets in the buses, so be careful and do not let your stuff unattended
- Bring some food along
- Bring something to entertain you, like books and music
- depending on the weather, you might also bring sea-sickness pills. Stay on the lower floors of the ferries and rather in the back of the boat to avoid the sway of the boat

Comment: I was SO tempted to leave just the first line there :)

Comment: Would travelling by plane be cheaper?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of travel options when you want to travel from Manila to Boracay. You either travel by air or by sea. You should take note that there are no airports on the island of Boracay, frankly because it is quite small. The fastest way to get there, of course, would be to go by plane from Manila to Boracay.A plane ride will take you as far as Caticlan or Kalibo where the closest airports to Boracay are located. Both the flights from Manila to Kalibo and Caticlan will take around an hour and a half. You then ferry from Caticlan to the island of Boracay.

For those who prefer a more leisurely mode of transport, or are on a budget travel, you can take the ferry boat from Manila to Dumaguit. Dumaguit is situated on the northern side of Panay.

First you have to drive to North Harbor in Manila where the ferries to Dumaguit are stationed. Once you arrive at Dumaguit you have to go to Caticlan. This can be done either by bus, or if you like, the jeepney.

Another way to get to Boracay from Manila is to take the following route: first you take a bus ride going from Manila all the way to Batangas. From there you will board the ferry that transports you to Tablas in Romblon. From the port of Odiongan, you can take a jeepney to another port (either Santa Fe or Looc) and get a banca to Boracay Island.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same "problem" on my trip to The Philippines last year. Initially, I used,as uncovery suggested "traditional" methods.

Then I discovered a site to rent a vehicle from other people.

The site is book2wheel and cover most of Philippines site. It was quite easy, but consider that sometimes the bike is not available, anyhow the site offers different models and owner. At the I rented a bike for one week paying something like 6000 pesos (which is something like 30 dollars)!

It was more comfortable because you have a bike 24h with you. However in some city driving is difficult, but in most cities is really cal and easy to drive.

Comment: To the users who read this answer, be careful, book2wheel is a motorcycle renting service, not bike or cars.

Comment: Actually, I saw on the site that they also have auto:) 
I think it depends on the city...
Best,